# How do I get the username of a member of a discord server from their user id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been looking through the docs, and I found the get_members function, but when I used this function and I try to get the name or nick or nickname field, it returns an error saying that the attribute doesn't exist. Here's my code:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=ctx.message.server.get_member(row[0]).nickname,  color=embedColor)
```

Here's the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nickname'
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting the exact error you are encountering?

Comment: @Adrijaned, I edited the post.

Comment: `get_member` returns `None` if it can't locate the specified member.  Could you `print(row[0])` and `print(type(row[0]))` before this line?  Also, what version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, this printed the correct result, which is my id (255658882007826434). And I do not know how to check the version, does get_member use a string or int for the id?

Comment: @otherwall That's why I asked for the version.  try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`.  Version 0.16 uses strings, and version 1.0.0 uses ints.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I'm using 0.16. It still returned the same error when using strings.

Comment: @otherwall So your id should be a string

Comment: @PatrickHaugh check my edit.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh my issue was that I thought row[0] was a string but it wasn't, and I didn't know that this command only returned nicknames, not whatever the person's name was on the server.

Answer (score 0):

row[0] was, in fact, not a string. And the attribute I was actually looking for was "name."